# Allow user to assume an IAM role with SSO login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-sso

I am trying to allow a user to assume a role on AWS. I attached an assume role policy to a group where the IAM user belongs so that they can assume a particular role. The problem is that the user now uses SSO to login and and is no longer allowed to login into through console with the IAM user credentials, therefore the user is unable to assume the role. How can I configure a user with SSO login to assume an existing IAM role? When i created the Assume role policy I chose both AssumeRole and AssumeRoleWithSaml. But it's still not working.

This is what the AssumeRole policy looks like

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole",
            "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/KinesisFirehoseServiceRole--us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
]
```

The Trust relationship for the role looks like this

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 10):

I managed to enable SSO users to assume a role in the account they were authenticated to by using the following.  Note that you'll need to replace `${ACCOUNT_ID}`, `${SSO_ROLE_NAME}`, and `${ASSUMABLE_ROLE_NAME}`.  You may, of course, need to repackage the bits.

```
aws iam create-role --role-name ${ASSUMABLE_ROLE_NAME} --assume-role-policy-document file://policy.json --profile $PROFILE
```

policy.json:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
            "aws:PrincipalArn": [
                "arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/*/AWSReservedSSO_${SSO_ROLE_NAME}_*",
                "arn:aws:iam::${ACCOUNT_ID}:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_${SSO_ROLE_NAME}_*"
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you, Erik.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specifically allow that user / role to be able to assume that role. Right now, the Principal is set to only allow the "firehose service" to assume that role.

The 2nd problem is that you need to specifically allow a SSO account to be able to access it. You'll need to get the ARN of your current SSO user session. To get this you should run `aws sts get-caller-identity`

You should get something like this

```
{
    "UserId": "BROA5DAM2TACHAA38V9J1:daryl.teo@appetiser.com.au",
    "Account": "1234567890",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_abe68abec87ew/something.username"
}
```

Or a 1 liner `aws sts get-caller-identity --output text --query Arn`

Then take that value and add it to your policy as an additional policy statement.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":
            {
                "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":
            {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::1234567890:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_abe68abec87ew/something.username"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
    ]
}
```

And now you can use:

`aws sts assume-role --role-arn=arn:aws:iam::123456823432:role/NameOfYourRole --role-session-name=role-session-name`

Comment: What if I didn’t want to allow a specific user, but rather some set of users in a permission set? I am basically trying to let users in a development account assume a role in a production account

Comment: @jr. a permission set creates a Role so you should be able to just specify the Role as a principal in your assumerole policy. It starts with AWSReservedSSO. Do note that I've had difficulty restricting the trust relationship of the target Role to the source PermissionSet that I have never solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [IAM Identity Center (SSO) Permission Set with a customer managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetcustom.html#permissionsetscmpconcept):

1. Create the role, `MyTargetRole`, in the target account, 111122223333, with a [trust policy allowing all principals in the account](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/) (a.k.a. `:root`, which is *not* the AWS account root user)

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Create a policy, `AssumeMyTargetRole`, in the target account that allows `sts:AssumeRole`:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/MyTargetRole"
  }
}
```

3. In the IAM Identity Center, create a [Permission Set with a customer managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/permissionsetcustom.html#permissionsetscmpconcept) named `MyTargetRole`

By configuring the permission set for a given SSO user and the target account, that SO user is allowed to assume `MyTargetRole`.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to everyone that responded. Turns out that i needed google saml identity provider and not AWS SS0 and I was able to complete the task using these instructions provided by aws.You can access the aws documentation via the link. [google saml sso with AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-set-up-federated-single-sign-on-to-aws-using-google-workspace/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).